# Haskell Division of all elements of a list

Tags: list, haskell, divide

I have a problem with this function, that should divide all elements of a list.

```
[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6] = (((((x1/x2)/x3)/x4)/x5)/x6)
```

My code thus far is:

```
division :: [Double] -> Double
divis    :: [Double] -> Double
divis []      = 0
divis [x]     = x
divis (x1:xs) = ????
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a left fold. Have a look at `foldl` or `foldl'`...

Comment: Note that `(((((x1/x2)/x3)/x4)/x5)/x6) = x1/(x2 * x3 * x4 * x5 * x6)` so your non-empty case could be `divis (x:xs) = x / product xs`.

Comment: This function doesn't really make sense mathematically. Why would `[] -> 0`? If anything, it's `0/0`; at best you could coax it to `1` or perhaps `Infinity`, but not to `0`. – Really I'd _start with one element_ as the base case: I think you want the signature `divis :: Double -> [Double] -> Double`, then you can simply do `divis x₀ xs = divis x₀ / product xs`.

Comment: It would make more sense for `divis [] = 1` (the nullary product), so that `divis (x:[]) == divis [x] == x`. Currently, this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

so i found 2 sollutions. thx to Alec and Mark Seemann

```
divis :: [Double] -> Double
divis [x] = x
divis (x1 : xs) =  x1 / mul xs
```

and

```
div2 :: [Double] -> Double
div2 (x1:xs) = foldl (/) x1
```

Comment: Worth noting that `divis []` is undefined and `div2 []` is `1`. Not `0` as in your question. This sort of ties back to  @leftaroundabout's point.

Comment: Also worth noting that you shouldn't ever use `foldl` in real programs. And `mul` is probably `product` from `Prelude`?